# How do I compare a quadratic model to data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, r-squared

I have a model which is quadratic (e.g. $y = k x^2$).  I'm comparing it against a large set of data (galaxy cluster masses) which spans several Log10 decades (e.g. $10^{11}$ to $10^{15}$ solar masses).  What is the right way to say how good the data fits the model?  Obviously the errors in the heavier galaxy clusters are going to count for more than the errors in the lighter clusters if I compare on a linear scale.

The blue line is the data, the red line is the model.

[image]

Is it valid to convert the values and errors to their logarithms (Log10) and perform the chi-square on those values?

Comment: Because $y=kx^2$ is manifestly *not* logarithmic, could you clarify what you mean by "logarithmic"?  Would your model perhaps actually be $\log(y) = \log(k) + 2\log(x)$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I made the correction.